# what happens when i remove doctype in html?

Tags: html, doctype

what is the use of doctype in html and is it valid to use html page with out doctype?. what is the default format when i remove doctype in html. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Without a Doctype:

1. Browsers enter Quirks mode and try to deal with your code as if it was written in the late 90s. This means they emulate many bugs that existed in their predecessors. They aren't particularly consistent about how they do this (so you'll get significantly different results in, for example, Firefox and Internet Explorer).
2. You will add a validation error to your markup
3. Validation tools won't be able to tell what specification to validate against unless you tell them though some other method

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the DOCTYPE is to tell the browser what kind of HTML you are writing. No, it is not valid to omit the DOCTYPE. There is no "default" format. The browser will just try to parse the html the best it can. But not all elements will display correctly. The DOCTYPE is a required part of all HTML documents.

HTML5's DOCTYPE is !DOCTYPE html

Answer (score 0):

Basically what will happen is that you'll get your page rendered in a "standards mode".

The only reason why you probably shouldn't use the new DOCTYPE is if you want to use XHTML 1.0 markup and conform to XHTML 1.0.

The downside to using HTML5 now is that the spec can change. This makes it important for you to keep up with the spec as it actively changes.

With that being said, I've already started using the new syntax in my pages. Also it guarantees that your page will last for a very, very, long time.